# Convert WideString to String

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe

How can I replace the empty widestring characters from a string?

e.g:
'H e l l o' convert to 'Hello'

I read an text blob field from a DB, and want to store it in another table. When I read it, I get the extra spaces, when I store it the extra spaces remains, and cannot be read correctly at the next query.

DXE, Firebird 2.5

**UPDATE**:
I use the IBQuery -> DataSetProvider -> ClientDataSet without desin-time created fields. 
It seams, that the IBQuery retrieves the data in that wrong format.

Current Write Code:

```
blobStream := TStringStream.Create;
...
blobStream.WriteString(blobText); //blobText = 'H e l l o';
ibsql.ParamByName('ABLOBCOL').LoadFromStream(blobStream);
...
ibsql.ExecQuery;
...
```

In the FB database is 'H e l l o' stored, but it must be 'Hello'. Since it seems to be a bug in IBQuery, I need a way to convert that string.

Comment: You've asked the wrong question. You don't want to remove spaces. You want to interpret the data correctly in the first place. Can you show the code that created the string.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, I'm not going to attempt to describe how to remove every other character from a string. Whilst that might appear to solve your problem it merely papers thinly over the gaping cracks. What you have here is a classic text encoding mismatch. The real solution to your problem will involve fixing the mismatch.

I suspect the problem arises in code that you have not shown. As I understand your question now, you have a `string` variable `blobText` that contains incorrectly encoded text. But the code in the question takes `blobText` as input, and so the damage has already been done by the time we reach the code in the question. The key to solving this is the code that puts duff data into `blobText`.

You need to find the code which assigns to `blobText` and sort out the encoding problem there. It looks like you have taken UTF-16 encoded text and interpreted it as if it had an 8 bit encoding. I could speculate as to how that would happen, but it would be better for you to look at the actual code, the code that assigns to `blobText`. If you cannot work it out, please do post an update to the question.

I'm pretty confident that there are no bugs in the database libraries and that this is just an encoding mismatch.

Comment: That didn't help. For now, I just changed the TIBQuery code and included it into my project. When the fields are created, I always return ftWideMemo instead of ftMemo now. Not sure if that bug is already fixed above Delphi XE?

Comment: Well, I still don't know what version of Delphi you use, and what you did the "didn't help". I doubt there's a bug anywhere other than in your code.

Comment: As mentioned in my question I use DXE and Firebird 2.5. Blob texts in firbird 2.x are always treaded as DataType ftMemo, when the IBQuery component is used. Then the TClientDataSet with its DataSetProvider loads the field definitions from the IBQuery and converts the ftMemo DataType as TMemoField. Which leads the problem descibs above. When the CDS is using a TWideMemoField, then the values are correct (without the spaces 'H e l l o').

Comment: OK, I did not make DXE into a Delphi version. Question tags help!

Comment: That means, the problem is not in writing the data but in reading the data from the DB. When the data are read like 'H e l l o', it's already a Unicode string, and cannot be converted anymore, since the space ' ' is treaded as a valid character.

Comment: See my latest update. The problem would appear to be, exactly as you just said, in the code that is not shown in the question. Find out what is putting diff data into `blobText` and you will be on the way to solving this.

Comment: So, let's see the code that reads the blob containing text. Please also make sure you specify what encoding was used to populate the source DB.

Comment: i am not sure that bad work wit hFirebird would be considered a bug in Interbase Express.Perhaps you would have to reproduce it with IB server

Comment: *When the data are read like 'H e l l o', it's already a Unicode string, and cannot be converted anymore, since the space ' ' is treaded as a valid character* if that is no - then that is not the spaces but - in your specific case - a #0 instead. Google for UTF-16